# How can I add an authentication file on bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I want to add google storage credentials on bitbucket. These credentials are set in a json file, and that json file's path is set inside an environment variable named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I could put this file inside my repository and set an environment variable to point to it's path, but I don't want to expose my credentials in my repository. Is there any way to add authentication files on bitbucket? All I can do is store ssh keys and api keys in bitbucket's configuration, but I can't seem to store any authentication files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to add authentication/permission for perticular file/folder in bitbucket.  https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-i-set-files-folders-permissions-in-Bitbucket/qaq-p/78962

Environment variables are not ment to commit. You can always refer them in `.gitignore` so that git doesn't track the file for changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to set a permission to a file, what I want is to upload a authentication file on bitbucket so that my repository can access that file's credentials. Think of it as instead of putting my api key in bitbucket's configuration, I put it in a file.

Comment: Bitbucket repo has nothing to do with the execution of the source. So technically bitbucket repo dont need credential information alongsilde your source code.